# cross-browser scroll bar that 'overlays' div content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm looking for a solution that is very similar to `overflow-y: overlay` used in webkit browsers i.e. **does not change div width upon applying scroll bar**, but it needs to work for every browser.

I was using overlay, but when I found myself starting to write hacks for firefox and ie/edge to change the overflow style on lists to make up for the unsupported overlay, I quickly realized I needed a better solution.

I like the idea of just setting `overflow-y: auto`, but I have a grid of content that is so precisely styled that when the few pixels on the scroll bar are added, it messes up the entire layout of the list...

Another thought is to always apply `overflow-y: scroll` and adjust div width to support the scroll bar, and then make it visible on :hover, but I'm not sure what a cross-browser solution to this would look like.

I've seen many solutions that work for specific browsers i.e.

- webkit: `overflow-y: overlay;`
- ie/edge: `-ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar`

But is there no general solution that all browsers accept!?

Comment: I can personally recommend [malihu scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) as a jQuery scrollbar solution for this kind of thing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion:

```css
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 150px;
  width: calc(100vw + 1.5ch);
}

/* 
1.5ch is equivalent to the scrollbar length, at least on my end.
You can change 100vw to something else, it is the width you had.
*/
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Hello!</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will affect modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome, Edge and Safari) scrollbar

```css
/* Firefox */
* {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
  scrollbar-color: #dedede #ffffff;
}

/* Chrome, Edge, and Safari */
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #ffffff;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #dedede;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
```